# Python Pandas - can not draw correct chart with two columns. In col 1 are several values of type A and several of type B. In col 2 are numbers

Tags: python, pandas, csv, charts, xls

I have table in xls that I need to visulaise in chart. Im using Python Pandas. Table has this structure:

| ORP | Produkce_obyv._kg |
| --- | --- |
| a | 289,77 |
| a | 333,31 |
| ... | ... |
| b | 198,69 |
| b | 214,71 |
| ... | ... |

Im using this code:

```
group1 = data[data['ORP']=='A']  
group2 = data[data['ORP']=='B']

graf = group1.groupby('ORP')['Produkce_obyv._kg'].mean().to_frame(name='A')
graf['B'] = group2.groupby('ORP')['Produkce_obyv._kg'].mean()

graf.plot.bar()
plt.show()
```

Chart prints only one bar (A):
[image]

I need to see data (B) as second bar.
I am using them for statistcs:

```
ttest_ind_result = ttest_ind(group1['Produkce_obyv._kg'], group2['Produkce_obyv._kg'], equal_var=False)
print(ttest_ind_result)
```

That works fine.
Where is problem with chart? Thanks!

I tried to use different library, tried to use analysis

```
print(graf.isna().sum())
and
print(len(group2))
print(group2['ORP'].unique())
```

All seems to be correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, taking the data in the question, you could plot this with `matplotlib` quite quickly.

The main difference is the use of `df.groupby('ORP').mean()` as you will see below.

here is an example:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# example data
data = {'ORP': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b'],
        'Produkce_obyv._kg': [289.77, 333.31, 309.42, 271.53, 367.32, 351.37, 198.69, 214.71, 244.35, 224.15]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)



# do the plot
grouped = df.groupby('ORP').mean()
grouped.plot(kind='bar')

plt.xlabel('ORP')
plt.ylabel('Produkce_obyv._kg')
plt.title('Average Produkce_obyv._kg by ORP')

plt.show()
```

and this is the result:

[image]